# Build times for Jekyll site are getting longer and longer

Tags: jekyll

The load times for my Jekyll site are getting larger and larger with each regeneration. I'm not quite sure why. See this screenshot:

[image]

How can the site build time go from 6 seconds to 71 seconds with just a dozen changes? I'm not making radical changes with each edit. I think something else may be coded wrong.

Comment: why did this get down-voted?

Comment: Hi, Tom. Downvoters are not important. For your particular problem, you can have a look at jekyll repository issues and maybe fill one if you don’t find an answer. I know that Jekyll 3.x will get serious build performance improvements.

Comment: I want to try out the 3.0 beta, but honestly I'm not sure how to install it. I tried running `gem install jekyll --pre`, but when I check my jekyll version (`jekyll --version`) it always says 2.5.3.

Comment: Do a `gem uninstall jekyll`

Comment: is it possible to run a specific version of jekyll per project?  i have one project publishing to Github Pages, so if I uninstall 2.5.3, won't Github Pages reject my build?

Comment: You can have a look at https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv this is very helpfull and allows to play with different ruby versions and different set of gems

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Jekyll 3.0pre version. Installation is simple,but  keep in mind that:

```
gem install jekyll --pre
```

installs beta version of Jekyll but will not update your PATH. When you use RVM to keep track of your different ruby versions your binaries are located inside .rvm directory.Beta gems binaries going three level lower in my case it is:

```
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.0.pre.beta6/bin
```

so to use it side-by-side make symbolic link to beta version and left v.2 as it is.